# How to give path while using exceljs writefile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, exceljs

I don't want to create that excel in my main directory, i have an another folder for these excels but how can i path it? I cant see anything about pathing in docs[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w463m.png)

Answer (score 0):

`fileName` contains the name of file and should also contain the path if you provide it there.

Something like this:

```
var completePath = "myDirectory\\" + fileName;
```

Maybe you want to try with just `\` or even `/` or `//`